# Condense many tables with overlapping information into one table

Tags: excel

I have an excel workbook with 15 worksheets.  Each worksheet contains one table with a list of species.  There is quite a bit of overlap of species among the worksheets.  So I'm trying to reduce that overlap by merging everything into a table.

I need to condense all 15 worksheets into one table that lists all of the species one time, and then shows if each species was present in worksheet X.  So basically the first column would be all of the species, the column names would be each worksheet, and the body of the table would be check marks indicating if the species appeared in worksheet X.  Here is an example:

```
Worksheet 1                             Worksheet 2
Species                 Species Code    Species                Species Code
Casurina equisitifolia  caeq            Odocoilius virginianus odvi
Columbrina asiatica     coas            Gavia immer            gaim
Gavia immer             gaim            

The table I want to create
Species                 Worksheet 1 Worksheet 2
Casurina equisitifolia  Y           N
Columbrina asiatica     Y           N
Gavia immer             Y           Y
Odocoilius virginianus  N           Y``
```

Comment: could you share what you have tried so far,

Comment: In this case, it would be really useful to see an example of your sheets and expected results

Comment: @Zac I included an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve this. Below is one approach:
First create a new worksheet (referenced as `Sheet1` for this example) in your workbook. Add the names in column "A". Now add your sheet name as a header in respective columns. Then add the below formula in cell "B2":

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0)),"N","Y")
```

Where `Sheet1!A2` holds the name you are looking for. `Sheet2!$A:$A` is your first sheet that holds the names (in column "A" of `Sheet2` for this example). This will give you "Y" if the name exist or "N" if it doesn't exist. Now drag the formula cell down the length of names and it will give you what you need for sheet 2. Repeat this process for each of the sheets you have and you should have what you need. Hope this helps

Comment: No worries, glad it helped. Just a after thought, you could fully automate this using VBA